# Math.h (not the usual)

Tags: c, gcc

A couple days ago I had the atan function from math.h working properly, but for some reason it's no longer compiling.  I get the usual

> 'broken_code.c:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to 'atan'

I'm including the `-lm` flag when I compile.

I've tried compiling and running it on a different system (both another Linux system and BSD-based system), and it works fine.  I don't really know anything about how a compiler works/links things, so any help would be appreciated.
Here's my code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double y1, x1, y2, x2;
    y1 = 0;
    x1 = 0;
    y2 = 1;
    x2 = 0;

    y1 = atan((y1-y2)/(x1-x2));
    printf("%lf\n\n", y1);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `" I don't really know anything about how a compiler works/links things"` gcc compiles your code (source files .c) to assembly code (.asm) , assembler (gas\nasm) turns it to `.o` (binary) and `ld` linker, links all `.o` into a one image.

Comment: As an aside, you should not divide by 0.

Comment: @TonyTannous: No. There is no intermediate ASM step. You can make GCC _generate_ ASM output, but that is actually a seperate backend step. `.o` is directly generated, i.e. there is never any ASM involved unless you _specifically_ ask the compiler to create it.

Comment: @DevSolar I am aware, gcc uses an external assembler and there's no need to do it yourself.

Comment: @TonyTannous: No, you misunderstood me. *There is no step of `.c` to `.asm`.* The compiler turns `.c` *directly* into `.o`. There is no "external assembler". Assembler is a different language. It doesn't play any role here.

Comment: @DevSolar I understand very well the compiler turns the `.c` into `.o`.

Comment: BTW: Look into using `atan2(y1-y2, x1-x2)` instead of `atan((y1-y2)/(x1-x2))`

Comment: @Yunnosch Interesting to note, my computer's apparently happy to divide by zero if they're floating points.

Comment: @chux I actually did see that while trying to figure out what stupid thing I did wrong, but figured I'd stick to what I know should work before trying something new.

Comment: @meep And the result is something you can do anything meaningful with?

Comment: @DevSolar, I understand very well how gcc turns my `.c` to `.o`. Gcc actually produces assembler and assembles it using the gas\gnu assembler? no intermediate step for a programmer, but not all compilers do that.

Comment: @TonyTannous: **NO.** GCC **does not** produce assembler **unless** you **explicitly** tell it to via the `-S` option, effectively telling it to turn RTL representation into ASM source instead of object code. I know the man page tells you differently, but when compiling C to `.o` *there is no internal ASM step involved*. Please refer to the [relevant section of the GCC Internals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Passes.html#Passes) documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you linked the math library in the wrong order.
For example

```
gcc -lm prog.c
```

might not work while

```
gcc prog.c -lm
```

will

Comment: I thought I tried that earlier, but apparently not.  Also one of the sites I looked at actually said it didn't matter.  Either way it worked, so thanks!

Comment: It depends on the linker.
I think modern linkers will search in all libraries while older ones go from left to right.

Comment: @rici: [http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_18.html](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_18.html)
`"Most current linkers will search all libraries, regardless of order, but since some do not do this it is best to follow the convention of ordering libraries from left to right."`
I thought that too, but i tried it and it seemed that my current linker has no problem at all.
Anyways it would be good to always use the correct linking order.

Comment: @osiris: gnu-ld and gold only look for unresolved symbols in files listed after the one containing the unresolved symbol. The MS linker and lld ( the LLVM linker) first check in the current library (if the unresolved symbol comes from an object in a library) and then in all libraries on the command-line. What "most" means in this context isn't clear to me. It's common for people (including me) to say "most" when we mean "the ones I personally am familiar with", which is why I deleted my other comment.

Comment: @rici:
First: You are right. The gnu-ld only look for unresolved symbols in libraries listed after.
Second: If the math library would be a static library the linker would give an error if it is written before the executable. Since math is a shared library it seems that the library is linked anyway if there is no `--as-needed` linker flag.
So `gcc -Wl,--no-as-needed -lm prog.c` should link, and the different behaviour of different distributions is only due to different default linking flags. I hope i understood this correctly.